# Scipy output of Kolmogorov–Smirnov test

Tags: python, numpy

I have made a call for the KS-test function on python to compare two features: size and duration, and I am kind of lost in explaining the output. Here is my code:

```
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
import csv

ds1=getColumn("TraceBG.csv",5)
ds2=getColumn("TraceFG.csv",5)
ds11=getColumn("TraceBG.csv",6)
ds12=getColumn("TraceFG.csv",6)

print "size: | ",ks_2samp(ds1,ds2)
print "duration: | ",ks_2samp(ds11,ds12)
```

I get this as an output:

> size: |  (0.25583333333333336, 0.0039023335557401583)
>
> Duration: |  (0.11504409325067666, 0.092596990959821421)

I know from the scipy webpage of the KS-test that the first one is a statistical value, and the second is a p-value. but how to explain exactly which feature is better from this values??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics. Stats questions are on-topic at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: should i create a new account there?

Comment: If you click `log in`, it should prompt you to create a new account that's linked to your SE network profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KS test is associated with a null hypothesis: The groups being compared are sampled from the same population.

If the null hypothesis is true, the p value is the probability of observing the particular deviation between the sampled groups.

For size, the observed level of deviation is to be expected in 0.3% of sample runs.

For duration, the level of deviation is seen 9% of the time.

What feature is better? If the task is to try to discriminate one population group from another, size is likely to be better.

Comment: yes, i want t discriminate a population group th another, so we only compare the p-value, the first one doesnt matter right?

Comment: The p-value is a function of the first value. Yes, you can focus on the p-value alone.